# Can't display array of JSONObjects in ListView - Android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview, android-studio

I am currently creating an app wich is supposed to collect JSONObjects (or Groups) from a server and then print them in a ListView. I've succeded to parse the JSONObjects and can iterate through and print all the groupnames in the LogCat but when i try to populate my ListView it always come out empty.

This is my TCPConnection class where i connect to server:

```
public class TCPConnection {

private Controller controller;

private RunOnThread thread;
private Receive receive;
private Socket socket;
private DataInputStream input;
private DataOutputStream output;
private InetAddress address;
private int connectionPort;
private String ip;
private Exception exception;
private MainActivity main;

private static String id;

public TCPConnection(String ip, int connectionPort, MainActivity main) {
    this.ip = ip;
    this.connectionPort = connectionPort;
    this.main = main;
    thread = new RunOnThread();

}

public void setController(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}


public void connect() {
    thread.start();
    thread.execute(new Connect());
}

public void disconnect() {
    thread.execute(new Disconnect());
}


public void newMessage(final String answer) {
    main.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String message = answer;
            String type;
            JSONObject jObj = null;

            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(message);
                type = jObj.getString("type");

                if(type.equals("register")){
                    recieveID(jObj);

                } else if(type.equals("groups")){
                    getAllGroups(jObj);

                }else{
                    Log.i("TCPConnection", "Type does not exist");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


//SENDING JOBJ to CONTROLLER
public void getAllGroups(JSONObject jObj){
    Log.i("GRUPPER", "Jobj sent to controller");
    controller.setAllGroups(jObj);
}


private class Receive extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        String result;
        try {
            while (receive != null) {
                result = input.readUTF();
                newMessage(result);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) { // IOException, ClassNotFoundException
            receive = null;
        }
    }
}


private class Connect implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d("TCPConnection","Connect-run");
            address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            Log.d("TCPConnection-Connect","Skapar socket");
            socket = new Socket(address, connectionPort);
            Log.d("TCP-CONNECT", "SOCKET INITIALIZED");
            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            Log.d("TCP-CONNECT", "INPUTSTREAM INITIALIZED");
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            Log.d("TCPConnection-Connect","Strömmar klara");
            receive = new Receive();
            receive.start();
        } catch (Exception e) { // SocketException, UnknownHostException
            Log.d("TCPConnection-Connect",e.toString());
            exception = e;
        }
    }
}

public class Disconnect implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (socket != null)
                socket.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
            thread.stop();
            socket.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            exception = e;
        }
    }
}


public void send(String JSONQuery) {
    thread.execute(new Send(JSONQuery));
}


public class Send implements Runnable {
    final String JSONQuery;

    public Send(String JSONQuery) {
        this.JSONQuery = JSONQuery;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            output.writeUTF(JSONQuery);
            output.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            exception = e;
            newMessage("EXCEPTION");
        }
    }
}
```

Then i have my controller:

```
public class Controller {

private MainActivity activity;
private CommunityFragment communityFragment;
private TCPConnection connection;
private boolean connected = false;

ArrayList<String> groupList = new ArrayList<String>();

public Controller() {
}

public Controller(MainActivity activity, CommunityFragment communityFragment, TCPConnection connection) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.communityFragment = communityFragment;
    communityFragment.setController(this);
    this.connection = connection;
    connection.setController(this);
    connect();
}


public void allGroups() {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(stringWriter);
    Log.i("MyConnectService", "setAllGroups() kördes");
    try {
        jsonWriter.beginObject().name("type").value("groups").endObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("MyConnectService", "setAllGroups fail");
    }
    connection.send( stringWriter.toString());
}

public void setAllGroups(JSONObject jObj) {

Log.i("GRUPPER", "groupList iteration start");
    groupList.add("TEST");

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArr = jObj.getJSONArray("groups");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            Log.d("GRUPPER", "RECIEVED IN LOOP: " + jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("group"));
            groupList.add(jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("group").toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("GRUPPER", "error in getMembers() for " + e);
    }
    Log.i("GRUPPER", "groupList iteration - Done!");
}

public ArrayList<String> getGroupList(){
    Log.i("GRUPPER", "groupList collected by communityFrag");
    return groupList;
}

}
```

And this is my CommunityFragment who contain the listView and also this is where you create groups

```
public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment {

private Controller controller = new Controller();

private EditText etGroup;
private EditText etMember;
private Button btnSave;
private ListView lvGroups;

private String groupName, userName;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);

    initializeComponents(rootView);
   // controller.allGroups();
    initializeAdapter();

    return rootView;
}


public void setController(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}


private void initializeComponents(View rootView) {
  .
  .
  .
        }
    });
}


public void initializeAdapter() {
    ArrayList<String> groupList = controller.getGroupList();
    //Adapter definierad och sätts till list fragmentet

    mArrayAdapter = new GroupAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.lv_groups, groupList);
    lvGroups.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    Log.i("GRUPPER", "Adapter created");
}

}
```

Here is the GroupAdapter:

```
public class GroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ArrayList<String> ArrayListGroups;
private int Resource;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater vi;

public GroupAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    ArrayListGroups = objects;
    Resource = resource;
    this.context = context;

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        //recycling views using viewholder (items getting offscreen)
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.groupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_title);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    //setting text in each item based on the position in the list
    holder.groupName.setText(ArrayListGroups.get(position));
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView groupName;
}
public void updateList(){
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
10-29 13:34:32.962  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-29 13:34:32.962  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:33.002  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-29 13:34:33.002  31680-31699/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/TCP-CONNECT﹕ SOCKET INITIALIZED
10-29 13:34:33.002  31680-31699/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/TCP-CONNECT﹕ INPUTSTREAM INITIALIZED
10-29 13:34:33.002  31680-31699/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/TCPConnection-Connect﹕ Strömmar klara
10-29 13:34:33.002  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:33.122  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:33.142  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4  QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
    Build Date: 03/20/14 Thu
    Local Branch: 0320_AU200_patches
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
        Reconstruct Branch:
10-29 13:34:33.182  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-29 13:34:33.202  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 199
10-29 13:34:33.202  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 200
10-29 13:34:33.212  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:33.212  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-29 13:34:33.212  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
**10-29 13:34:33.212  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication I/GRUPPER﹕ Jobj sent to controller
10-29 13:34:33.212  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication I/GRUPPER﹕ groupList iteration start
10-29 13:34:33.212  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/GRUPPER﹕ RECIEVED IN LOOP: blajje
10-29 13:34:33.212  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication I/GRUPPER﹕ groupList iteration - Done!**
10-29 13:34:33.212  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:96 height:96 bitmap id is 201
10-29 13:34:33.312  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:33.322  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:35.162  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
10-29 13:34:35.162  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:35.992  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:36.022  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 203
10-29 13:34:36.022  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 204
10-29 13:34:36.022  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 205
10-29 13:34:36.032  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 206
10-29 13:34:36.032  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 207
10-29 13:34:36.032  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 208
10-29 13:34:36.032  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 209
10-29 13:34:36.042  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 210
10-29 13:34:36.042  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 211
10-29 13:34:36.042  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:78 height:96 bitmap id is 212
10-29 13:34:36.062  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
**10-29 13:34:36.062  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication I/GRUPPER﹕ groupList collected by communityFrag
10-29 13:34:36.062  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication I/GRUPPER﹕ Adapter created**
10-29 13:34:36.062  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:36.082  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
10-29 13:34:36.382  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
10-29 13:34:36.382  31680-31680/se.mah.sofand.mapapplication D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
```

NOTE there is only one group created so that's why only 'blajje' is visible.

As you can see the list is defined before the adapter is created, still i can't display it. No Nullpointer or other exception occur. Any ideas why?

Comment: Debug your own app and come asking more precise questions. I would not hold my breath expecting anyone here doing that for you.

Comment: I find this question precise, my listview won't display the objects i want to, i don't know why and i would need some help. If you're not up to it you don't have to, period.

Answer (score 0):

The controller you use here

```
public void initializeAdapter() {
    ArrayList<String> groupList = controller.getGroupList();
```

is not set to use any data. It is initialized (`= new Controller()`) but after that you do nothing with it. It has no data to work with. I think you have to do that here, with the method you already created in the Controller class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);

    initializeComponents(rootView);
    // controller.allGroups();

    controller.setAllGroups(); // this line should set the data
    initializeAdapter();

    return rootView;
}
```

If the controller instance has no data set, there is no data passed to the list adapter hence no data is displayed.

Edit

The Controller instance you use is initialized like this

```
private Controller controller = new Controller();
```

However, Controller class has 2 constructor

```
public Controller() {
}

public Controller(MainActivity activity, CommunityFragment communityFragment, TCPConnection connection) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.communityFragment = communityFragment;
    communityFragment.setController(this);
    this.connection = connection;
    connection.setController(this);
    connect();
}
```

It appears you are using the wrong constructor, because the empty one that you currently use does not initialize the TCPConnection instance `connection`.

If you initialize your Controller instance with the right constructor, that nullpointer will be gone.

Comment: Thank you but now i get a Nullpointer in the controller when i transfer the request to TCPConnection.

Comment: it crashes here: `    public void setAllGroups(){
        connection.allGroups();
    }
´

Answer (score 0):

```
I have checked the code, find that in this part:
public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment {

private Controller controller = new Controller();

}


When you init Controller, you should use this constructor

public Controller(MainActivity activity, CommunityFragment communityFragment, TCPConnection connection) 
{
    this.activity = activity;
    this.communityFragment = communityFragment;
    communityFragment.setController(this);
    this.connection = connection;
    connection.setController(this);
    connect();
}

You can try this.
```